# Why would my SQL Server join take far longer with 129 records in a table compared to 128?

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I am doing a basic join in SQL Server at work. I thought it was taking an incredibly long time for what it is (joining a table with about 2000 records to another with about 500).

Here's what the query looks like:

```
select
     an.AccountNumber
    ,d.AccountCharacteristic
    ,st.TotalBalance
from AccountLevelData as d
join Statements as st
    on st.AccountNumber = d.AccountNumber 
join #AccountNumberList as an
    on an.AccountNumber = d.AccountNumber 
where st.TimePeriod = eomonth(getdate(), -1)
```

The `#AccountNumberList` is just a temp table I'm using to filter down the result set to a subset of accounts that I care about. I started debugging this query and noticed it ran lightning fast if I filtered `#AccountNumberList` down to containing only 128 accounts, but took extremely long to finish or would not finish at all if it contained 129 accounts.

I suppose this has to do with a quirk in SQL Server or SQL Server Management Studio, but I was unable to find any resources on why or how this happens. I did notice that 128 = 0b10000000, so maybe it has something to do with bits - once the number of rows in the table takes more than seven bits to represent the query optimizer does something weird?

Comment: What's the execution plan look like? It's absolutely possible statistics throw things off (thats the nature of statistics, there's a tipping point somewhere) but I'd be extremely surprised if the 128 number was anything but coincidence

Comment: `c.AccountNumber` the c alias is not declared in the provided query, re-check your query, the first join should be on the main table (accountleveldata), second join should be depended on the first join.

Comment: Sorry, the c’s should have been d’s — I changed table names for clarity and forgot to edit some places. Regarding join order, it shouldn’t matter for the result set, correct? It’s just to help the query optimizer?

Comment: You must not only look at the number of account numbers in your temp-table but also on how many account numbers are there in "d" and "st" and how many records do these tables contain. Are there any Indexes on the `AccountNumber` fields?

Comment: The “d” table has about 2000 records, the “st” table has hundreds of thousands but only thousands for the given date. They are both indexed on AccountNumber. I’m not at work right now so I will provide an update on execution plans and join order effect when I get in on Monday.

Comment: As mentioned in the first comment, check the query plans between the two. It's highly likely they'll be different. It might have something to do with incorrect statistics in temp tables. Here's a good article although it doesn't directly relate to your problem because I guess you are only populating the temp table once: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/statistics-matter-on-temp-tables-too/

Comment: When the query execution gets stalled  - run `sp_who2`, examine blocked spids list.

Answer (score 0):

since the Statements table is the largest one, then you could flip the query a bit like this :

```
SELECT
    an.AccountNumber
,   d.AccountCharacteristic
,   st.TotalBalance
FROM 
    #AccountNumberList an
JOIN Statements st ON st.AccountNumber = an.AccountNumber AND st.TimePeriod = eomonth(getdate(), -1)
JOIN AccountLevelData d ON d.AccountNumber  = an.AccountNumber
```

If this still runs slower than it should, then you need to check the tables indexes and their performance.

For instance, you could exclude Statements from the above query, see how it perform with AccountLevelData table, if the performance is as expected, then comment out AccountLevelData join, and then test the Statements join. continue your testing until you hit the jackpot. (Don't forget to check the execution plan for each test).

Check all indexes, (basically, disable all indexes, and leave the one you want to use, test the query, if the query performed faster and issue is solved, then you can check the indexes that causing the issue).

You might need also to update the statistics for the indexes. So, do that as well.

Comment: FWIW, the query optimizer usually (always?) ignores what order you actually specify the tables in (unless you instruct it not to)

Comment: Please don't proliferate the myth that putting tables in different orders in a trivial query like this makes any difference. It doesn't

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm not proliferating any myth, i'm simply using the join as a replacement of the WHERE, so the query optimizer when it checks it, it will have less data than joining the whole table. Then, it's up to the it to decide. I've also used the temp table to make things easier to test (no need to rewrite, just comment out a join and its ready to test). since the temp always faster than the permanent tables.

Comment: In all likelihood your rewritten statement will have an identical query plan. Rearranging table order usually rarely makes any difference. Moving join's to where's rarely makes any difference. temp tables are not always faster.

Comment: The optimizer knows that it doesn't matter logicaly where the conjuncts of ONs & WHEREs are distributed among a sequence of inner joins, and it will rearrange them to optimize.

Answer (score -1):

Its because you may not set index to the table.You can add a index to the table and look at the query execution plan to optimize the query better.